# Know which WCF binding has been used to communicate with the service

Tags: c#, wcf

I've a WCF service that is accessible through 2 differents bindings, one TCP and one NamedPipe. The NamePipe one is used only locally for speed reason, and on the Service side I need to know if I've been called locally(from the same computer, through the namedpipe) to enforce some licensing constraints.

What would be the way to go? I've seen there is a `OperationContext.Current` but I didn't find any information on the current binding in use, so I guess there is another way to get it(or at least know that I've been called from the same computer).

Comment: @DeanOC : How detecting the address is usefull to me?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageproperties(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
// check if context is not null
MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
```

If the request came from a browser, you will get a [HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) object,
which contains a property [IsLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal(v=vs.110).aspx) which true if the request is from the local computer; otherwise, false.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Well, my goal is more to know if the call has been made locally or remotely(and in my case it's either from a TCP Binding or a Named Pipe binding). So the request will not contains any HttpRequest with a IsLocal property

Comment: Understood, you will not receive HttpRequest object, however you may try to examine IncomingMessageProperties for both cases i.e. TCP Binding or a Named Pipe binding and see if there is anything which might help you to distinguish requests from different clients, do update your findings on this question.
Happy Programming !